# How can I use map and receive an index as well in Scala?

Tags: scala, functional-programming, dictionary

Is there any List/Sequence built-in that behaves like `map` and provides the element's index as well?

Answer (score 168, accepted):

I believe you're looking for zipWithIndex?

```
scala> val ls = List("Mary", "had", "a", "little", "lamb")
scala> ls.zipWithIndex.foreach{ case (e, i) => println(i+" "+e) }
0 Mary
1 had
2 a
3 little
4 lamb
```

From: http://www.artima.com/forums/flat.jsp?forum=283&thread=243570

You also have variations like:

```
for((e,i) <- List("Mary", "had", "a", "little", "lamb").zipWithIndex) println(i+" "+e)
```

or:

```
List("Mary", "had", "a", "little", "lamb").zipWithIndex.foreach( (t) => println(t._2+" "+t._1) )
```

Comment: Well, I meant using the `zipWithIndex` method to get the index inside a loop/map/whatever.

Comment: For example comparing to a `while` loop, which is probably among the fastest options.

Comment: An Array and a while loop is probably as fast as it can get.

Comment: @ziggystar If you're looking for performance you need to trade off some immutability. Look inside the zipWithIndex function. It just uses a var to build a new collection of pairs. You could use the same method of incrementing a var without building the new collection, just as you would do in Java. But it's not functional style. Think if you actually need it.

Comment: So it seems even zipWithIndex itself is not functional style.  Anyway I think it should be mentioned that using `view` you should be able to prevent creating and traversing an extra List.

Comment: Don't use view, use ``iterator``, views are on the way out.

Comment: If you are concerned with efficiency see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9137644/how-to-get-the-element-index-when-mapping-an-array-in-scala

Comment: Is it possible to use zipWithIndex and get the indices as Int, instead of Long, without using further mapping? And about spark, wouldn't zipWithIndex be more efficient because of the distribution of data?

Answer (score 77):

Use .**map** in .**zipWithIndex**

```
val myList = List("a", "b", "c")

myList.zipWithIndex.map { case (element, index) => 
   println(element, index) 
   s"${element}(${index})"
}
```

Result:

```
List("a(0)", "b(1)", "c(2)")
```

Comment: This is the first decent example I've seen that used a `map` as requested instead of just printing inside a `foreach`.

Answer (score 12):

The proposed solutions suffer from the fact that they create intermediate collections or introduce variables which are not strictly necessary. For ultimately all you need to do is to keep track of the number of steps of an iteration. This can be done using memoizing. The resulting code might look like

```
myIterable map (doIndexed(someFunction))
```

The `doIndexed`-Function wraps the interior function which receives both an index an the elements of `myIterable`. This might be familiar to you from JavaScript.

Here is a way to achieve this purpose. Consider the following utility:

```
object TraversableUtil {
    class IndexMemoizingFunction[A, B](f: (Int, A) => B) extends Function1[A, B] {
        private var index = 0
        override def apply(a: A): B = {
            val ret = f(index, a)
            index += 1
            ret
        }
    }

    def doIndexed[A, B](f: (Int, A) => B): A => B = {
        new IndexMemoizingFunction(f)
    }
}
```

This is already all you need. You can apply this for instance as follows:

```
import TraversableUtil._
List('a','b','c').map(doIndexed((i, char) => char + i))
```

which results in the list

```
List(97, 99, 101)
```

This way, you can use the usual Traversable-functions at the expense of wrapping your effective function. The overhead is the creation of the memoizing object and the counter therein. Otherwise this solution is as good (or bad) in terms of memory or performance as using unindexed `map`. Enjoy!

Comment: This is a very elegant solution to the problem.  +1 for not creating a temporary collection.  Won't work in a parallel collection, but still a very nice solution.

Comment: If you don't want to create a temporary collection, just use `coll.view.zipWithIndex` instead of `coll.zipWithIndex`

Answer (score 6):

Or, assuming your collection has constant access time, you could map the list of indexes instead of the actual collection:

```
val ls = List("a","b","c")
0.until(ls.length).map( i => doStuffWithElem(i,ls(i)) )
```

Comment: A more elegant way to do this is simply:

`ls.indices.map(i => doStuffWithElem(i, ls(i))`

Comment: @aksiksi Well, seeing that [`indices` is implemented as `0 until length`](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/2.12.x/src/library/scala/collection/SeqLike.scala#L668) it's pretty much the same thing :P

Comment: downvote because of complexity - iterating with ls(i) takes O(n^2)

Comment: @MosheBixenshpaner Fair enough. My example of `List` was indeed poor. I did mention however that this is suitable if your collection has constant access time. Should have picked `Array`.

Answer (score 5):

There is `CountedIterator` in 2.7.x (which you can get from a normal iterator with .counted).  I believe it's been deprecated (or simply removed) in 2.8, but it's easy enough to roll your own.  You do need to be able to name the iterator:

```
val ci = List("These","are","words").elements.counted
scala> ci map (i => i+"=#"+ci.count) toList
res0: List[java.lang.String] = List(These=#0,are=#1,words=#2)
```

Answer (score 5):

There are two ways of doing this.

***ZipWithIndex:*** Creates a counter automatically starting with 0.

```
  // zipWithIndex with a map.
  val days = List("Sun", "Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat")
  days.zipWithIndex.map {
        case (day, count) => println(s"$count is $day")
  }
  // Or use it simply with a for.
  for ((day, count) <- days.zipWithIndex) {
        println(s"$count is $day")
  }
```

Output of both code will be:

```
0 is Sun
1 is Mon
2 is Tue
3 is Wed
4 is Thu
5 is Fri
6 is Sat
```

***Zip***: Use zip method with a Stream to create a counter. This gives you a way to control the starting value.

```
for ((day, count) <- days.zip(Stream from 1)) {
  println(s"$count is $day")
}
```

Result:

```
1 is Sun
2 is Mon
3 is Tue
4 is Wed
5 is Thu
6 is Fri
7 is Sat
```

Answer (score 3):

Use **.map** in **.zipWithIndex** with Map data structure

```
val sampleMap = Map("a" -> "hello", "b" -> "world", "c" -> "again")

val result = sampleMap.zipWithIndex.map { case ((key, value), index) => 
    s"Key: $key - Value: $value with Index: $index"
}
```

Results

```
 List(
       Key: a - Value: hello with Index: 0, 
       Key: b - Value: world with Index: 1, 
       Key: c - Value: again with Index: 2
     )
```

Answer (score 0):

If you require searching the map values as well (like I had to):

```
val ls = List("a","b","c")
val ls_index_map = ls.zipWithIndex.toMap
```