# How to get the element index when mapping an array in Scala?

Tags: arrays, scala, dictionary, scala-collections

Let's consider a simple mapping example:

```
  val a = Array("One", "Two", "Three")
  val b = a.map(s => myFn(s))
```

What I need is to use not `myFn(s: String): String` here, but `myFn(s: String, n: Int): String`, where `n` would be the index of `s` in `a`. In this particular case myFn would expect the second argument to be 0 for s == "One", 1 for s == "Two" and 2 for s == "Three". How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 77, accepted):

Depends whether you want convenience or speed.

Slow:

```
a.zipWithIndex.map{ case (s,i) => myFn(s,i) }
```

Faster:

```
for (i <- a.indices) yield myFn(a(i),i)

{ var i = -1; a.map{ s => i += 1; myFn(s,i) } }
```

Possibly fastest:

```
Array.tabulate(a.length){ i => myFn(a(i),i) }
```

If not, this surely is:

```
val b = new Array[Whatever](a.length)
var i = 0
while (i < a.length) {
  b(i) = myFn(a(i),i)
  i += 1
}
```

<sup>(In Scala 2.10.1 with Java 1.6u37, if "possibly fastest" is declared to take 1x time for a trivial string operation (truncation of a long string to a few characters), then "slow" takes 2x longer, "faster" each take 1.3x longer, and "surely" takes only 0.5x the time.)</sup>

Comment: I love reading your answers on speed stuff, but it can be so depressing sometimes... :-)

Comment: How does the speed of `a.view.zipWithIndex.map{ case (s,i) => myFn(s,i) }` compare to your solutions?

Comment: @gzm0 - Even slower (by 2-5x) than the slowest if you actually need all the values.  If you only need a few, then the view is better.

Answer (score 5):

A general tip: Use `.iterator` method liberally, to avoid creation of intermediate collections, and thus speed up your computation. (Only when performance requirements demand it. Or else don't.)

```
scala> def myFun(s: String, i: Int) = s + i
myFun: (s: String, i: Int)java.lang.String

scala> Array("nami", "zoro", "usopp")
res17: Array[java.lang.String] = Array(nami, zoro, usopp)

scala> res17.iterator.zipWithIndex
res19: java.lang.Object with Iterator[(java.lang.String, Int)]{def idx: Int; def idx_=(x$1: Int): Unit} = non-empty iterator

scala> res19 map { case (k, v) => myFun(k, v) }
res22: Iterator[java.lang.String] = non-empty iterator

scala> res22.toArray
res23: Array[java.lang.String] = Array(nami0, zoro1, usopp2)
```

Keep in mind that iterators are mutable, and hence once consumed cannot be used again.

---

An aside: The `map` call above involves de-tupling and then function application. This forces use of some local variables. You can avoid that using some higher order sorcery - convert a regular function to the one accepting tuple, and then pass it to `map`.

```
scala> Array("nami", "zoro", "usopp").zipWithIndex.map(Function.tupled(myFun))
res24: Array[java.lang.String] = Array(nami0, zoro1, usopp2)
```

Comment: "iterators are mutable, and hence once consumed cannot be used again" - I've once spent some time debugging why doesn't a program work to find an iterator to get empty once used :-)

Answer (score 5):

What about this?  I think it should be fast and it's pretty.  But I'm no expert on Scala speed...

```
a.foldLeft(0) ((i, x) => {myFn(x, i); i + 1;} )
```

Answer (score 0):

Index can also be accessed via the second element of tuples generated by the `zipWithIndex` method:

```
val a = Array("One", "Two", "Three")
val b = a.zipWithIndex.map(s => myFn(s._1, s._2))
```