# Scala: increment value while mapping for lists

Tags: scala

I have a list of strings, like

```
val myList = List("apple", "orange", "pear")
```

I would like to transform it to a string like "1) apple 2) orange 3) pear".
I could write a for loop, but I think that in Scala there should be an one-liner for things like this.
The best one-liner I could come up with was

```
val myString = myList.map(s => "1) " + s).mkString(" ")
```

But this results in "1) apple 1) orange 1) pear". How can increment a value while mapping a list?

Comment: This is helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2213323/how-can-i-use-map-and-receive-an-index-as-well-in-scala

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Easy peasy (scala 2.10 with [string interpolation](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/string-interpolation.html)):

```
myList.zipWithIndex.map { case (cases, i) => s"${i + 1}) $cases" }
```

Comment: Thank you, a plus is missing after (i+1), but after adding that it is working. Now I only have to understand it :)

Comment: Oh, this version is even better :)

Answer (score 2):

I honestly wouldn't recommend it, but you *can* actually get your version working:

```
val myString = myList.map{var i=0; s => i+=1; i + ") " + s}.mkString(" ")
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually, there is no missing plus sign. Try it.
My minor modification is to add mkString at the end.

```
myList.zipWithIndex.map { case (cases, i) => s"${i + 1}) $cases" }.mkString(" ")
```

Comment: Well, there [was](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/16969249/1) missing plus sign :-)

Comment: A small improvement suggestion, add `view` before zipWithIndex `myList.view.zipWithIndex.map { case (cases, i) => s"${i + 1}) $cases" }.mkString(" ")`

so that the intermidiate list will be init in a lazy way

Answer (score 0):

My Solution is:

```
myList.map{value => s"${myList.indexOf(value)+1}) $value"}
```