# Convert to Map from list in Gatling

Tags: scala, scala-collections, gatling

I need to form this:

```
{
“item” : “hardcoded_value”,
“item2” : “hardcoded_value”,
“item3” : “hardcoded_value”,
}
```

In the exec block I am trying:

```
// list with items [“item1”, “ item2”, “ item3”]
val theList = session("itemNames").as[List[String]]

val theMap = Map.empty[String,String]     // empty map

// add items from list in map
theList.foreach{ key =>
                      | theMap += key -> "hardcoded_value"
}
```

But getting error at += position.

Also tried:

```
theList.foreach(key =>  theMap += key -> "hardcoded_value" )
```

How to insert key and value into a map by iterating over a list? I am new to gatling and scala.

Answer (score 0):

After looking at your question in more detail, I realize that you're not just asking about turning the Collection into a Map.  Combining the answers from [How can I use map and receive an index as well in Scala?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2213323/how-can-i-use-map-and-receive-an-index-as-well-in-scala) and [Scala best way of turning a Collection into a Map-by-key?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/674639/scala-best-way-of-turning-a-collection-into-a-map-by-key), you can do the following:

```
List("first", "second", "third").zipWithIndex.map {
  case (item, index) => ("item" + index) -> item.toString
}
>res0: List[(String, String)] = List((item0,first), (item1,second), (item2,third))
```